# MacOS Wireless Diagnostics 802.11 Reporting

Tags: macos, wifi

Something that seemed confusing to me and thought everyone here could probably help clarify:

As far as I know, 802.11ac transmits in 5GHz only. I know most devices that are capable of 802.11ac are also dual-band (transmit at 2.4GHz as well), however my question is regarding how the 802.11 version is being reported in MacOS's Wireless Diagnostics and some other tools I've used.

These programs are reporting 802.11ac in the 2.4GHz band. I figured that if a device was dual band, it would use 802.11ac in the 5GHz band and 802.11n (or maybe even g) in the 2.4GHz band. I'm confused as to why I see programs reporting 802.11ac in the 2.4Ghz band if according to spec it only transmits in the 5GHz band?

Thanks for the help!

** EDIT: Forgot to mention - I did a capture and looked at it in Wireshark and the network was listed as 802.11g in the 802.11 radio information. However, it still is reported as 802.11ac in Wireless Diagnostics. I verified the BSSID and Channel line up between Wireshark and Wireless Diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

There're some proprietary implementations wherein the MCS 8 and 9 are also used in 2.4G band thereby using the VHT preamble for the same. The phy type is set to VHT/11ac in that case.

Typically this is possible only with enterprise APs. Try this experiment with low end retail AP.

Did you check the rates that were negotiated during Assoc exchanges?

Also check the MCS in the diagnostics. If it's 8 or 9, can you try moving the Macbook away from the AP to see lower MCSs ( 7 or below) being used. I presume in that case it would report 11n or 11g.